# Jquery invalid character

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

We use jquery for a slider and for some users in our company who access the website, they  get object doesn't support this property and the slider doesn't load.

The website works fine in all major browsers (IE 8, firefox, chrome) and seems to be user specific? For example I load IE 8 and go to the website, the website loads fine,another user accesses the website and they get the error? any ideas, where would you start to test security for jquery?

Thanks

Comment: try to change the order of your js files.

Comment: It would probably be good to know which specific browsers (including IE's compatibility mode) have this problem. Additionally, a live example would be awesome, but if that is not available, then relevant code snippets would be nice.

Comment: It shows in IE8, unfortunately for me I'm not allowed to show the website :-( but it is is failing on <script src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>

Comment: I've also tried to change the order of the js no luck, it must be something to do with the individual user security settings because on some users there are no errors. Actual error is:Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1;
Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)

Timestamp: Mon, 24 Oct 2011 07:42:22 UTC

Message: Invalid character

Line: 1

Char: 1

Code: 0

URI: http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.5/full/jquery.tools.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of IE errors happen with the option hash and a trailing `,`. Note the `,` after true of option2

WRONG:

```
$("#id").plugin({
    option1: true,
    option2: true,
})
```

GOOD:

```
$("#id").plugin({
    option1: true,
    option2: true
});
```

Comment: @manual thanks for the suggestion, checked the jquery and it is correct, it just odd how it works on some sites  and not others

Comment: it was the security on our network blocking the jquery. Thanks for the suggestions.